# Unable to install Visual Studio 2017 (result code 0x0, 0x2)

Tags: visual-studio, installation, failed-installation, visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to install Visual Studio 2017 RC for the past two hours but so far, I have not been able to install any version of Visual Studio. I have tried looking around for solutions, but so far nothing.

[Here's an image of running the installer. This is about as far as it goes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl8WW.png)

After doing this, the installer just exits and kills itself and no installation happens. Waited for a while and nothing happens. No installer applications running in both task manager and resource manager, so I'm assuming it right after it reaches that.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
This computer is clean and has never install or attempt to install any version of MS Visual Studio before.

```
[1/17/2017, 16:12:46] === Logging started: 2017/01/17 16:12:46 ===
[1/17/2017, 16:12:46] Executable: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\vs_Community.exe v15.0.26020.0
[1/17/2017, 16:12:46] --- logging level: standard ---
[1/17/2017, 16:12:46] Directory 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2a6df70b7a7d7cb06efead\' has been selected for file extraction
[1/17/2017, 16:12:46] Extracting files to: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2a6df70b7a7d7cb06efead\
[1/17/2017, 16:12:47] Extraction took 828 milliseconds
[1/17/2017, 16:12:47] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' '
[1/17/2017, 16:12:49] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[1/17/2017, 16:12:49] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x2
[1/17/2017, 16:12:49] === Logging stopped: 2017/01/17 16:12:49 ===
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it turns out that some part of the installation was trying to read from a config and failing. After running it a few times, it eventually created a folder called "VSFaultInfo", and it contained a `ConfigurationErrorsException`.

My problem was that I edited my `machine.config` at one point, and the installer was getting an exception from trying to read from it. It installed when I undo-ed the modifications I made. My config was located under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config", but it might be different for you. Try to delete it or find a VSFaultInfo folder on your computer.

Comment: I also edited `machine.config`. And I had to spoil a whole day as my Visual Studio stopped working next day. I uninstalled VS and VS Installer and cleared cache and played with the registry, did everything I found on the web, and finally found out the problem was due to `machine.config` editing. Here I make a suggestion. If you need to add any setting to the `machine.config` file, add at the end before the end tag `</configuration>`. The error could be something like `machine.config` is corrupt instead of silent program termination. Your answer helped me for Visual Studio  2019. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most Visual Studio installer problems since VS2012 are caused by corrupt packages that is has downloaded. The log file you posted suggests this might be the case.

The packages are downloaded to the temp directory in user accounts `\AppData\Local\` folder as indicated in the log file. I would suggest that you clear out all files in this directory and run the installer again, triggering it to re-download required packages which are hopefully no longer corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the error message, the installation met issues when extracted or launched the package. Make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up the %temp% folder, then re-run the VS 2017 installer as **administrator**.

In you have tried to install any VS 15 preview versions or re-install the VS 2017, you can perform a manually uninstall like the following:

1. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, if there have ‘Microsoft Visual Studio 2017’ or ‘Microsoft Visual Studio Installer’, right click it and choose ‘Uninstall’
2. Try to delete the following installed folders: (you can back up those folders before any modification, in case we need to roll back)

•   Go to the folder: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and delete the ‘Packages’ folder

•   Go to the Visual Studio installation folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio) and delete the folder ‘2017’ or ‘VS15Preview’ if you have

After the uninstallation, then re-download [the VS 2017 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/) and run as administrator.

Comment: 'Packages Folder' ! 80% cause of this issue , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out a problem after over an ENTIRE week of searching and messing around with settings. I can actually do my homework normally now (whoo hoo...).

Like so, I have tried everything you guys have said to no avail, although the solutions you guys have provided did solve some of my classmates' problems, so thank you for that.

So here is what I did:

1. Press Start (windows icon) + R to open up the 'Run' window.
2. Type in services.msc to open the 'Services' window.
3. Scroll down and find 'Windows Management' Instrumentation, right-click it, then click 'Start'.
4. Look at the 'Startup Type' and see if it says 'Manual (Trigger Start).' If it does not say that, right-click on it, click on properties and set the 'Startup Type' to automatic.
5. Run the installer as an administrator and install.

So if anybody has this problem, try enabling services. Some of these services are required in order for Windows to actually allow the application to install. In this case, it was a service which retrieves information from the computer in order for the installer to install properly.

I disabled this service previously in order to improve hard drive performance, with no awareness that it restricted me from installing software.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Korywon, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and you can mark your reply as answer, that will helpful for other community members who meet the same or similar issue to check this service.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I had unknowinly messed up with `machine.config`

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
```

I reverted the changes to default and the installation started well at last.