# visual studio 2017 Can not install

Tags: visual-studio, file, installation

I had visual studio 2015, through windows settings I did "refresh" (deleted all applications),
And now that I'm trying to download visual studio 2017, I can not extract the initial files,
That means that after he reaches this window it's closing :

[image]

Comment: Hi yeo4, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here. Before the installation, make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software and clean up %temp% folder, re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator to install. I found a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708167/unable-to-install-visual-studio-2017-result-code-0x0-0x2

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer:
A. Like you said, I cleaned up all the temp files I have and turned off the antivirus
B. Https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvUbykBAzp4Xn0cuCEZ1LsE1yDY9
third. I looked at the link you sent and saw that it was a case that I had vs15 but that Windus had deleted it (after I did refresh), so I think it was not deleted properly
D. I checked and also I can not download the version of VS15

Comment: You can try to follow the uninstallation methods that I described in the shared link to uninstall the VS 15 and VS 2017, if you can find those installation folders on your computer. From your log file, I found the error code '0x1389' often means other resources are depend on it, did you install VS 2017 on the computer that cannot connect the internet network?